# How can I delay the click button action just enough so i can store a JSON array?

Tags: java

Everything on the following code works, except if the user click one of the buttons to fast with no time to connect with the database and get the json values.

I tried to surround a try catch block and i tried to check create an if statement that checks the first character=='{' because this is the always the first character in the given json string.

This is the class

```
package com.example.allrateform;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import static com.example.allrateform.MainActivity.UsernameText;

public class Categories extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String Category;
    public static char[] TextList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);

        //CREATING ALL INSTANCES
        final Button ComputersButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ComputersButton);
        final Button HobbiesButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.HobbiesButton);
        final Button BooksButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BooksButton);
        final Button TourismButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.TourismButton);
        final Button GamesButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.GamesButton);
        final Button FantasyButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.FantasyButton);
        final Button SportsButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.SportsButton);

        final TextView TextViewUsername=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewUsername);
        TextViewUsername.setText(UsernameText);

        getJSON();

        ComputersButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Category="Computers";
                openQuestion();
            }
        });
        HobbiesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Category="Hobbies";
                openQuestion();
            }
        });
        BooksButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Category="Books";
                openQuestion();
            }
        });
        TourismButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Category="Tourism";
                openQuestion();
            }
        });
        GamesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Category="Games";
                openQuestion();
            }
        });
        FantasyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Category="Fantasy";
                openQuestion();
            }
        });
        SportsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Category="Sports";
                openQuestion();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openQuestion(){
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Question.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Categories.this);
            builder.setMessage("Try again later")
                    .setNegativeButton("Ok", null)
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }
    }

    public void getJSON() {
        new Categories.BackgroundTask().execute();
    }

    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        String json_url;
        String JSON_STRING;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            json_url = "https://allratejohnnycode.000webhostapp.com/List.php";
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(json_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                while ((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING + "\n");
                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            TextList=result.toCharArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to offer 2 different approaches.

The **1st** one is what you asked for, though I recommend the **2nd** one:

---

### Button click triggers a Circular Progress Loader

You can maintain a `boolean` representing whether the `JSON` was loaded or not,
so when the user clicks a button, you first check the boolean status. If loaded - continue with intent creation. Else - provide a Circular Progress Loader that would wait for the JSON to be loaded. (If you need assistance, comment me and i'll provide you with a code example).

---

### Use Android [View Model](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=Cj0KCQjw4fHkBRDcARIsACV58_EUX5dvySd3VWFEWoxeO-eHdmRhRVu1JTXL_8D_dWbLz1oNpsMv6kEaAhExEALw_wcB#java) Architecture

This is a more "heavy duty" solution, but after studying [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture) you'll realize this is the most clean & efficient way of loading data in the background, while maintaining a separation between data and UI in general. Very useful knowledge.

---

---

### 1st Method - Example of Implementation

Step 1: Add a progress bar, with `visibility="gone"` at the beginning. Design it as you wish.

Step 2: Try this code. It works (tested).

```java
public class Categories extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String Category;
    public static char[] TextList;
    //4 new variables
    private static volatile boolean isJsonLoaded, isButtonClicked;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private final Object locker = 0; //for concurrent modification & synchronization

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);

        TextView TextViewUsername = findViewById(R.id.TextViewUsername);
        TextViewUsername.setText(UsernameText);

        this.progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        isJsonLoaded = false;
        isButtonClicked = false;

        initButtons();
        getJSON();
    }

    //Slightly beautified your code
    private void initButtons() {
        //Temp array of buttons
        ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.ComputersButton),
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.HobbiesButton),
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.BooksButton),
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.TourismButton),
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.GamesButton),
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.FantasyButton),
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.SportsButton)
        ));

        //Mutual 'onClick' listener for all of them
        View.OnClickListener buttonClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Get the button's name
                String buttonName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(v.getId());
                //Eliminate the "...Button" part
                Category = buttonName.substring(0, buttonName.indexOf("Button"));
                handleButtonClick();
            }
        };

        for (Button button : buttons)
            button.setOnClickListener(buttonClick);
    }

    public void handleButtonClick() {
        synchronized (locker) {
            if (isJsonLoaded) openQuestion();
            else {
                isButtonClicked = true;

                //Show the progress bar
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    void openQuestion() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Question.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void getJSON() {
        new Categories.BackgroundTask().execute();
    }

    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        String json_url;
        String JSON_STRING;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            json_url = "https://allratejohnnycode.000webhostapp.com/List.php";
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(json_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                while ((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING + "\n");
                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            TextList = result.toCharArray();
            isJsonLoaded = true;
            synchronized (locker) {
                if (isButtonClicked)
                    openQuestion();
            }

            //Hide the progress bar
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I manage to create an alert dialog that blocks the question activity if the json is not stored yet. Anyway the first option might be best one for me. How exactly do you suggest I should implement the circular progress loader?

Comment: Just edited my post for you & provided an implementation. Synchronization is needed here due to your (justified) use of `AsyncTask`, which raises a background thread.